# preventDefault for copy & cut not working on andorid mobile

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, preventdefault

Doing device testing on Android 4.2 currently (HTC One) for disabling copying and cutting from an input field. It's working on iOS and BlackBerry devices but for the android it doesn't seem to do anything at all.

Here is my JS:

```
$('#user-input, #confirm-user-input').bind('copy cut', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The HTML is simple:

```
<input type="text" name="user-input" id="user-input>
<input type="text" name="confirm-user-input" id="confirm-user-inputm">
```

I've tried adding an alert('works'); to see if the event is even firing but doesn't appear so.

Comment: How about adding "click tap" to your `bind` group: `.bind(click tap copy cut...`?

Comment: @KJPrice --> Unfortunately no luck :(